# My nordvpn is not working and clicking on it will not do anything

Tags: networking, vpn

**Hi I have ubuntu 20.4.4 lts and when running nordvpn a fast terminal arm closes and nothing happens**

**this is my syslog:**

```
Apr 19 05:50:47 robbie nordvpnd[3175]: 2022/04/19 05:50:47 
rotating: transport rotator: can't find gateway
Apr 19 05:50:47 robbie systemd[1]: nordvpnd.service: Main process 
exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 19 05:50:47 robbie systemd[1]: nordvpnd.service: Failed with 

result 'exit-code'.
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie systemd[1]: nordvpnd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 24.
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie systemd[1]: Stopped NordVPN Daemon.
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie systemd[1]: nordvpnd.socket: Succeeded.
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie systemd[1]: Closed NordVPN Daemon Socket.
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie systemd[1]: Stopping NordVPN Daemon Socket.
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie systemd[1]: nordvpnd.socket: TCP_NODELAY failed: Operation not supported
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie systemd[1]: Starting NordVPN Daemon Socket.
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie systemd[1]: Listening on NordVPN Daemon Socket.
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie systemd[1]: Started NordVPN Daemon.
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 [Info] Daemon has started
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 Get "https://cdn.zwyr157wwiu6eior.com/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup cdn.zwyr157wwiu6eior.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.otmwumj6qw5em0zb.me/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.otmwumj6qw5em0zb.me: Temporary failure in name resolution
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.icpsuawn1zy5amys.com/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.icpsuawn1zy5amys.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.nordcdn.com/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.nordcdn.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.mzhlhrfr8z.info/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.mzhlhrfr8z.info: Temporary failure in name resolution
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.mxo4bkqvdityebzvp.xyz/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.mxo4bkqvdityebzvp.xyz: Temporary failure in name resolution
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.wutlk3t9mybdz.info/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.wutlk3t9mybdz.info: Temporary failure in name resolution
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 error on making client request: Head "https://cdn.zwyr157wwiu6eior.com/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup cdn.zwyr157wwiu6eior.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.se3v5tjfff3aet.me/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.se3v5tjfff3aet.me: Temporary failure in name resolution
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.x9fnzrtl4x8pynsf.com/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.x9fnzrtl4x8pynsf.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.ltlxvxjjmvhn.me/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.ltlxvxjjmvhn.me: Temporary failure in name resolution
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.tptn0rhbtj.info/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.tptn0rhbtj.info: Temporary failure in name resolution
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.ns8469rfvth42.xyz/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.ns8469rfvth42.xyz: Temporary failure in name resolution
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.njtzzrvg0lwj3bsn.info/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.njtzzrvg0lwj3bsn.info: Temporary failure in name resolution
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.judua3rtinpst0s.xyz/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.judua3rtinpst0s.xyz: Temporary failure in name resolution
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.p99nxpivfscyverz.me/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.p99nxpivfscyverz.me: Temporary failure in name resolution
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 error on making client request: Head "https://downloads.73dkt-vwrqs.xyz/configs/dns/cybersec.json": dial tcp: lookup downloads.73dkt-vwrqs.xyz: Temporary failure in name resolution
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie nordvpnd[3194]: 2022/04/19 05:50:52 rotating: transport rotator: can't find gateway
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie systemd[1]: nordvpnd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 19 05:50:52 robbie systemd[1]: nordvpnd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Hello. Contact NordVPN.

Comment: to uninstall and reinstall nordvpn sometimes works.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo purge nordvpn
```

download latest deb from
https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/pool/main/
you can use wget

```
sudo rm /var/lib/nordvpn/data/settings.dat
sudo rm -rf ~/.config/nordvpn
sudo dpkg -i the nordvpn deb file.
sudo apt update
sudo install nordvpn
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT; sudo iptables -F INPUT ; sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT; sudo iptables -F OUTPUT; sudo systemctl restart
```

last one is optional but if you have problems try it.

also if you don't want to use their web browser (without vpn yet) to login as per the terminal message at first

```
nordvpn login
```

use

```
nordvpn login --legacy
```

you can also go the gnome way
sudo wget https://downloads.nordcdn.com/configs/archives/servers/ovpn.zip
unzip that
nm-connection-editor

- button
  import a saved configuration.
  and choose the config you want. note you can edit this vpn connection with a new IP found in each config file.(they told me it was ok this way)
  then edit the ethernet/wireless connection in nm-connection-editor to auto connect to your vpn.

if perchance you want it to stop updating with other ubuntu updates.

```
sudo apt-mark hold nordvpn
```

and to release for update

```
sudo apt-mark unhold nordvpn
```

Comment: I currently get a hanging busy icon in terminal when trying that way to connect. I am using the gnome way for now. and if problems there either uninstall nordvpn or set nord  killswitch off.

Comment: copy pasting my comment at another thread.major news, new NordVPN Version 3.14.2  works for me in terminal . you might need to uninstall re above, though I did not. hell of a time this year (and earlier) with unbuntu/gnome network manager method, which frequently decided to connect a new ethernet connection without vpn, also asking for password when it was set ok before. I hope this lasts. clonezilla backup imminent.....