# Why does NordVPN Linux CLI on Ubuntu 22.04 fail to connect to any server?

Tags: command-line, upgrade, 22.04, vpn

I have just upgraded my headless sever from Ubuntu desktop 21.10 to 22.04 LTS. Prior to the 22.04 upgrade, NordVPN command line app worked flawlessly.

Now with 22.04, when I connect I just get this: `Whoops! Connection failed. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact our customer support`

Before I called NordVPN support, I performed the following to verify that the installed app wasn't incompatible with 22.04:

1. Uninstalled (purged) nordvpn: `sudo apt purge nordvpn`
2. Reinstalled *"nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb"* using `sudo dpkg -i nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb` ***Note: I downloaded this first from NordVPN website!!**
3. Updated the local package repository: `sudo apt update`
4. Reinstalled nordvpn: `sudo apt install nordvpn`

Result: SAME :(

Answer (score 2):

So I asked NordVPN sw engineers on their support page. For the meantime, this is their solution:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/resolvectl /usr/bin/systemd-resolve
```

From their support engineer:

> After, try connecting to our servers once more. If the issue persists,
> please provide us with the NordVPN application's connection logs. In
> order to do that, open the terminal and type this command:

```
sudo journalctl -u nordvpnd > ~/Desktop/daemonlog.txt
```

You will find a new file **daemonlog.txt** on your desktop.This would be the file to send to NordVPN support to debug your particular case.

Comment: Woks for me! =)

Comment: upvoted to get it back to zero, who on earth downvoted this? why? also I put in all I know here
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403181/my-nordvpn-is-not-working-and-clicking-on-it-will-not-do-anything/1403891#1403891

Comment: Yah, folks from (other)VPN.co?? Anyway, thanks @pierrely. The link you attached refers to Ubuntu 20.04 with NordVPN DEB installs/reinstalls but its related, yes. Thanks!!

Comment: major news, new NordVPN Version 3.14.2  works for me in terminal . you might need to uninstall re above, though I did not. hell of a time this year (and earlier) with unbuntu/gnome network manager method, which frequently decided to connect a new ethernet connection without vpn, also asking for password when it was set ok before. I hope this lasts. clonezilla backup imminent.....

Comment: @pierely Yes version 3.14.2 is the latest as I type here (10-9-22) and no longer have the error I noted in this post.

Answer (score 0):

After you install NordVPN, ensure that you run the following commands to login:

1. `su - $USER`, then enter your password.
2. `nordvpn login`, this will generate a link, right click on the link and open it, this will take you to the NordVPN login page. Login with your username and password for your NordVPN account. You will see a Terminal window open up and close. You are now logged in to NordVPN.
3. `nordvpn connect`, this will connect you to NordVPN.

Comment: an alternative to login (rather than have to open up a browser before the vpn is logged in to, which seems daft to me) is at terminal.
 nordvpn login --legacy 
worked for me as recently as this week.
and by golly, it is all working very well lately too, just on some reboots autoconnect not kicking in. while I am here, any basic connectivity issues, disabled the killswitch first, then reenable it when connected . this would be as intended to stop a non 'logged into nordvpn ' connection. then you can login

Comment: @pierrely, AWESOME!! that legacy login in terminal works again!! :D I wonder why NordVPN added the browser login for Linux app? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I gave them exactly that feedback. that is like going into a brothel for your first root without the condom, than they issue you with  a pack -  to put it crudely.  they are very good communicators. sometimes you get a standard help desk robot response, I tell them I am continuing their asked for feedback, and it goes to the right person.

Comment: oh, and adding, someone did a nice extension that works and shows the nord connectioin in the top bar with the  country and connection # ....  gNordVPN-local by gnord-local@isopolitio.com
for 22.04 wayland you might need to install   https://haydenjames.io/ubuntu-22-04-install-gnome-extensions-manager-workaround/

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue, and was able to make it work by running the below command:

```
nordvpn set technology openvpn
```

Now `nordvpn connect` works as expected. I have no clue as to why it fixes it, or why it started to fail in the first place.

This is what I see in the NordVPN logs after I activated them (thanks to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1407442/519573) on how to activate the logs)

```
...
Apr 18 18:33:09 <machine-name> nordvpnd[2922]: 2023/04/18 18:33:09 [Debug] picking servers for NORDLYNX technology
Apr 18 18:33:09 <machine-name> nordvpnd[2922]: 2023/04/18 18:33:09 [Info] starting vpn
Apr 18 18:33:09 <machine-name> nordvpnd[2922]: 2023/04/18 18:33:09 [Error] TELIO: telio_start_named: Err(AlreadyStarted)
Apr 18 18:33:09 <machine-name> nordvpnd[2922]: 2023/04/18 18:33:09 [Error] TELIO: telio_start_named: Err(AlreadyStarted)
Apr 18 18:33:09 <machine-name> nordvpnd[2922]: 2023/04/18 18:33:09 [Warning] executing 'ip -4 rule del from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0' command: exit status 2: RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
Apr 18 18:33:09 <machine-name> nordvpnd[2922]: 2023/04/18 18:33:09 [Warning] executing 'ip -4 rule del not from all fwmark 57841' command: exit status 2: RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
Apr 18 18:33:09 <machine-name> nordvpnd[2922]: 2023/04/18 18:33:09 [Warning] executing 'ip -6 rule del from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0' command: exit status 2: RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
Apr 18 18:33:09 <machine-name> nordvpnd[2922]: 2023/04/18 18:33:09 [Warning] executing 'ip -6 rule del not from all fwmark 57841' command: exit status 2: RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
Apr 18 18:33:09 <machine-name> nordvpnd[2922]: 2023/04/18 18:33:09 [Error] opening the tunnel: starting libtelio on retry with boring-tun: 6
Apr 18 18:33:10 <machine-name> nordvpnd[2922]: 2023/04/18 18:33:10 [Error] TELIO: libtelio-build/libtelio/crates/telio-wg/src/adapter/linux_native_wg.rs:102 LinuxNativeWg: [GET01] Unable to get interface from WireGuard. Make sure it exists and you have permissions to access it.
Apr 18 18:33:11 <machine-name> nordvpnd[2922]: 2023/04/18 18:33:11 [Error] TELIO: libtelio-build/libtelio/crates/telio-wg/src/adapter/linux_native_wg.rs:102 LinuxNativeWg: [GET01] Unable to get interface from WireGuard. Make sure it exists and you have permissions to access it.
Apr 18 18:33:12 <machine-name> nordvpnd[2922]: 2023/04/18 18:33:12 [Error] TELIO: libtelio-build/libtelio/crates/telio-wg/src/adapter/linux_native_wg.rs:102 LinuxNativeWg: [GET01] Unable to get interface from WireGuard. Make sure it exists and you have permissions to access it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach (download DEB, add repo, install with apt; similar to the [installation approach described here](https://itslinuxfoss.com/install-nordvpn-ubuntu-22-04/)) did not work for me either.

Instead, I got it to work by running the script from the [NordVPN linux install page](https://nordvpn.com/download/linux/):

```
sh <(curl -sSf https://downloads.nordcdn.com/apps/linux/install.sh)
```

Note the instructions given by the output of this command:

```
Setting up nordvpn (3.16.3) ...
NordVPN for Linux successfully installed!
To get started, please re-login or execute `su - $USER` in the current shell, type 'nordvpn login' and enter your NordVPN account details. Then type 'nordvpn connect' and you’re all set! To allow other users to use the application run 'usermod -aG nordvpn otheruser'.
```

Then, as mentioned by @Petronilla Escarabajo above:

```
su - $USER
```

Enter password

```
nordvpn login
```

Follow browser login link

```
nordvpn connect
```

And I was able to connect