# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS - NordVPN can't detect OS

Tags: networking, vpn, nordvpn

For reasons I don't understand, NordVPN can't recognize my Linux Ubuntu OS. I did as NordVPN told be to and ran:

`sh <(curl -sSf https://downloads.nordcdn.com/apps/linux/install.sh)`

After installing curl. Then I logged into NordVPN through Firefox. When I click on the blue Connect button after logging in, that is when I get the screen that says it can't recognize my OS.

Comment: What did the NordVPN `install.sh` do? Now that it's too late, download and inspect the script. Should you have run it as `root`? I shudder at the idea, but choose your own risks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does NordVPN Linux CLI on Ubuntu 22.04 fail to connect to any server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407441/why-does-nordvpn-linux-cli-on-ubuntu-22-04-fail-to-connect-to-any-server)